# How to check which class the selected row is in DataGridView

Tags: winforms, if-statement, datagridview

**I've been searching with google/stackoverflow for a while, but I couldn't find proper answer for my problem.**

I have to create simple program in VS Windows Forms (.net Framework). I have created few DataGridViews with showing exact data I need. I added buttons to "Add" to create new row, or "Remove" selected row. Now I need to change data in selected row with single button click.
When I click "Add" button, new dialog window pop-up, where you choose from subclasses Car or Motorbike, then when you choose what to add, new dialog will pop-up, and there you fill proper information (like Manufacturer, or year of creation etc.)

When I want to "Edit" selected row, I want the app to directly go to dialog where you can change the data to new ones. I thought simple "if" could help me easily, but i cannot find the code to create it.
My thought was something like this:

```
            F1Automobil f1 = new F1Automobil();
            F1Motorka f2 = new F1Motorka();
            int indCar = dgvVozovyPark.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
            if (/*index of selected row where subclass equals to "automobil" = true)
            {
                {
                    f1.Action = F1Automobil.ActionType.Edit;
                    f1.CarInstance = (Automobil)dgvVozovyPark.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
                    f1.ShowDialog();
                }
            else
                {
                    f2.Action = F1Motorka.ActionType.Edit;
                    f2.BikeInstance = (Motorka)dgvVozovyPark.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
                    f2.ShowDialog();
                }
            }
```

But VS shows me several mistakes. Could somebody please help, because i don't know what to do. I tried a lot of combinations like `Database.Equals(something) = true`, but none worked.

Edit: Here is the base class with defined subclasses

```
namespace Semestrální_projekt___Půjčovna_vozidel
{
    [Serializable()]
    public class Vozidla
    {
        public string Vyrobce { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public int RokVyroby { get; set; }
        public int CenaVypujcky { get; set; }
        public int CenaProdejni { get; set; }
        public Vozidla(string vyrobce, string model, int rokVyroby, int cenaVypujcky, int cenaProdejni)
        {
            Vyrobce = vyrobce;
            Model = model;
            RokVyroby = rokVyroby;
            CenaVypujcky = cenaVypujcky;
            CenaProdejni = cenaProdejni;
        }
    }
        [Serializable()]
        public class Motorka: Vozidla
        {
            public int Kubatura { get; set; }
            public string Typ { get; set; }
            public Motorka(string vyrobce, string model, int rokVyroby, int cenaVypujcky, int cenaProdejni, int kubatura, string typ)
                :base (vyrobce, model, rokVyroby, cenaVypujcky, cenaProdejni)
            {
                Kubatura = kubatura;
                Typ = typ;
            }
        }
        [Serializable()]
        public class Automobil: Vozidla
        {
            public int ObsahMotoru { get; set; }
            public string Typ { get; set; }
            public string Prevodovka { get; set; }
            public int PocetMistSezeni { get; set; }
            public Automobil(string vyrobce, string model, int rokVyroby, int cenaVypujcky, int cenaProdejni, int obsahMotoru, string typ, string prevodovka,int pocetMistSezeni)
                :base(vyrobce, model, rokVyroby, cenaVypujcky, cenaProdejni)
            {
                ObsahMotoru = obsahMotoru;
                Typ = typ;
                Prevodovka = prevodovka;
                PocetMistSezeni = pocetMistSezeni;
            }
        }
    }
```

This may help

```
if (dgvVozovyPark.SelectedRows.Count > 0) {
  try {
    Vozidla vehicle = (Vozidla)dgvVozovyPark.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem;
    string className  = vehicle.GetType().Name;
    if (className.Equals("Automobil")) {
      Automobil selectedAuto = (Automobil)vehicle;
      MessageBox.Show("Open Automobil instance : " + selectedAuto.ToString());
    }
    else {
      if (className.Equals("Motorka")) {
        Motorka selectedMotor = (Motorka)vehicle;
        MessageBox.Show("Open Motorka instance : " + selectedMotor.ToString());
      }
      else {
        // unknown class
      }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex) {
    MessageBox.Show("Grid cast Error: " + ex.Message);
  }
}
```

Comment: [if-else (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/if-else)

Comment: [DateTime Struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: It sounds strange to be enrolled in a school without the ability to “communicate” with the teacher. How are you given assignments? If you are using a `DataGridView`, is there some reason you do not have the user “edit” the data in the grid “directly” by editing the individual cells? It is unclear what the issue is you are having with the “IF” statement. `If (grid.CurrentCell.Value.ToString() == “automobile”) {…}` ?

Comment: 1) Thanks for links to MS help. I've seen those pages, yet I didn't found them helpfull.
2) Yes, I can ask teacher thru email, but he has many students from "daily" programs, and my next Teams session is after a month or so, where you discuss mostly finished projects.
3) My selection in DGV is for full row, where, if you click on "Edit", all the data will load to that dialog window, where you will change them. And DGV shows whole class of "Vehicles", not separatedly cars in one, and bikes in second. Also, DGV shows a bit more columns, so it would be painfull to change every grid separatedly.

Comment: 3.1) I have class named Vehicles, where are 2 subclasses: Cars, Bikes. DGV shows all vehicles listed in 'BindingList<>'. My 'if' statement has to check, if selected row with 'Vehicle' is subclass of 'Car' or 'Bike', and then decide, which dialog window will pop-up.  I have such option with 'Customer' DGV, but I don't have subclasses of this List, so it was "very easy" to create new/edit buttons, because "if you click this button, you create new customer, and if you click this, you edit him"

Comment: 1) Sorry the links didn’t help. As far as an “IF” statement goes, it is about a basic as you can get and is usually explained/taught in the first semester of any beginning CS class. The second link is for a `DataTime` object. It is in reference to the second code snippet. It appears clear that whatever it is doing, it is setting the number of “days” from a given month. Unless this is an assignment using dates and it specifies to NOT use `DateTime` objects, then you are just “creating” more work for yourself.

Comment: 3.1) Since it is unknown what your `Vehicle` class looks like or how this class and its “subclasses?” are structured we have to guess. When you throw in “multiple” grids into the picture, we have to guess how those are structured. Without more info it would be speculation as to how to properly structure the “if” condition. It may help to post what these classes look like. I am assuming there is a “base” class “Vehicle”? And the “Car” and “Bike” classes inherit from “Vehicle” I am guessing this is what you mean by “subclass.” Again , this is speculation on my part. Can you clarify any of this?

Comment: 1) Thanks. I will rewrite my code with `DateTime`. I must've overlook this object. Thank you for help.

3.1)I will try to copy/paste whole code, so you might see my problem. Please notice that the code is only limited by comment max chars.: `namespace Semestrální_projekt___Půjčovna_vozidel
{
 [Serializable()]
 public class Vozidla
 {
  public string Vyrobce { get; set; }
  public string Model { get; set; }
  public int RokVyroby { get; set; }
  public int CenaVypujcky { get; set; }
  public int CenaProdejni { get; set; }`

Comment: Without going into detail, to help… Is what you want to do is cast the selected row to a `Vozidla` object “FIRST” before the “if”  statement. Then with the `Vozidla` object you can determine if it is a `Automobil` object or a `Motorka` object. The objects `GetType()` method may come in handy. Good Luck!

Comment: Yes, `DataGridView<dgvVozovyPark>` is bound to `BindingList<Vozidla>`, so it shows both `Automobil` & `Motorka` objects. I would apreciate details of this solution, since I want to learn it. I will reopen, so you may add solution. Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: I voted to reopen the question... try to reopen it if you can.

Comment: If you want to try to reopen your question…. 1) clean up the code, get rid of the comments and code about the numeric up down. It has nothing to do with the title of the question. You can only post ONE question per question. 2) Code wise… ONLY Post the three Classes and the current “If” statement. Then lastly, revise the description and focus on what the problem is. In this case how to check which class the selected row is.

Comment: Taking the effort to “edit” the question and actually make good improvements to the question will increase your chances of it getting reopened. If you ask to re-open it and don’t make any significant changes, chances are slim of it getting reopened.

Comment: I will add last comment. I would like to THANK A LOT to #JohnG. You saved my project, and myslef aswell. The solution you provided was absolutely perfect. THANK YOU again, great man !

Answer (score 0):

I will copy and paste answer from @JohnG if anyone want to see the help:

> This may help

```
if (dgvVozovyPark.SelectedRows.Count > 0) {
  try {
    Vozidla vehicle = (Vozidla)dgvVozovyPark.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem;
    string className  = vehicle.GetType().Name;
    if (className.Equals("Automobil")) {
      Automobil selectedAuto = (Automobil)vehicle;
      MessageBox.Show("Open Automobil instance : " + selectedAuto.ToString());
    }
    else {
      if (className.Equals("Motorka")) {
        Motorka selectedMotor = (Motorka)vehicle;
        MessageBox.Show("Open Motorka instance : " + selectedMotor.ToString());
      }
      else {
        // unknown class
      }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex) {
    MessageBox.Show("Grid cast Error: " + ex.Message);
  }
}
```